# How to pass table column values to function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql

Table source contains integer column. Its values should be passed to Postgresql 12 function for selecting data from other table.

I tried to use array

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.TestAddAssetTransactions(dokumnrs int[]) 
     RETURNS int AS
    $BODY$
    
    with i1 as (
    INSERT INTO bilkaib (dokumnr)
    select dokumnr  from dok where dokumnr in (select * from unnest(dokumnrs))
    returning *
    )
    
    select count(*) from i1;
    $BODY$ language sql;
    
    create temp table bilkaib (dokumnr int ) on commit drop;
    create temp table dok (dokumnr serial primary key ) on commit drop;
    create temp table source (dokumnr int ) on commit drop;
    insert into source values (1),(2);

select TestAddAssetTransactions( (select ARRAY[dokumnr] from source)::int[] )
```

but got error

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

How to pass single column values from table rows to function? Should array, table type or temp table used?

Using Postgresql 12+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the `int`s in your function call. Otherwise you're just casting each value to a single-element array and they try to cast a column to an array of `int`.

```sql
select TestAddAssetTransactions( (select array_agg(dokumnr)::int[] from source) );
```

[online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jGZEMWIy)

Comment: Thank you. Can `::int[]` cast removed? I tested and it worked without cast.

Comment: Sure. It's just good practice because `array_agg()` returns an array of whatever you feed into it. If you somehow feed `text`, it will break on function lookup, failing to find a function of that name that accepts `text[]` instead of `int[]`. When you cast on call, you'll get a cast error.